# Showing $\frac{2\sin\theta\cos i\phi}{2\cos\theta\sin i\phi}=\frac{\tan\theta}{i\tanh\phi}$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I have encountered a problem in an undergraduate Bsc course text book as follows.

$$\frac{2\sin\theta\cos i\phi}{2\cos\theta\sin i\phi}=\frac{\tan\theta}{i\tanh\phi}$$

I think this relation is not true. Please enlighten me. I tried by putting the trigonometric functions in their corresponding exponential forms, but the relation couldn't be established that way.

Comment: Why do you think that the relation is not true?  Please edit your question to show your analysis.

Comment: Hint: Convert to exponential forms ($\cos(\theta) = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$, etc.)

Comment: @JoshuaWang I tried that way, but couldn't get the relation.

Comment: In order for two fractions to be equal, it *need not* be true that the two numerators are equal (and the two denominators are equal).

Comment: By the way, the RHS should be $$\frac{\tan\theta}{i \tanh \phi}$$

Comment: @GEdgar yes, you have pointed right. Thank you

Comment: Use $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and $\tanh=\frac{\sinh}{\cosh}$, as well as the identities relating trig functions with complex argument to hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the proof is straightforward.

$\frac{2\sin\theta\cos i\phi}{2\cos\theta\sin i\phi}$

$=\frac{\sin\theta\cosh\phi}{\cos\theta i\sinh\phi}$

$=\tan\theta\times\frac{\coth\phi}{i}$

$=\tan\theta\times\frac{1}{i\tanh\phi}$

$=\frac{\tan\theta}{i\tanh\phi}$.